# Ethereum blockchain webhook API

Tags: web3js, blockchain

I am looking for an API service that allows my web app to generate Ethereum a deposit address, detect and notify a callback URL when a user sends ether to that address, and forward the funds to "cold" addresses.

Is there such a service out there? If not is there another way of programmatically detecting and forwarding deposits without running one's own Ethereum node?

Answer (score 3):

There is official [`Ethereum JavaScript API`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) which offer a Javascript based API to interact with an Ethereum node.

To send a transaction you can use [`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction)

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])
```

which offers a `callback` too.

#### To create an address you can try [`LightWallet`](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet#lightwallet)

generate a new address with [`keystore.generateNewAddress`](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet#keystoregeneratenewaddresspwderivedkey--num-hdpathstring)

```
keystore.generateNewAddress(pwDerivedKey [, num, hdPathString])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check [Blockcypher](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/), it's the only public service I could find that offers notifications via webhooks and websockets.

Comment: but this does not send web hooks if you are trying to work with erc20 tokens. Have you been able to see any workaround on erc20 transactions webhooks?

Comment: If you work with tokens, you have a smart contract which emits events. You can listen for these events if you run a geth node.

Comment: I built the smart contract event webhooks for QuikNode: https://blog.quiknode.io/introducing-webhooks-for-ethereum/

Answer (score 2):

Alchemy has a Notify API (available on the free tier) which allows you to create webhooks for transaction activity. It effectively allows you to detect whenever an address receives ETH. The forwarding logic will have to be done on your end of course since they don't store your private keys.

Here are the docs for the address activity webhooks, you basically input the account address you want to track and the webhook url you want data to be sent to: [Alchemy Docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/using-notify#address-activity)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this Telegram bot [@MyETH_bot](https://t.me/MyETH_bot)

It can:

- check your addresses every 30 seconds
- automatically send webhooks on each transaction of ETH and ERC20 tokens with data like: address, balance change, current balance, etc

Check https://myeth.io to learn more

Answer (score 0):

Alchemy provides [notify](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/notify-api#get-all-addresses-for-an-address-activity-webhook) which provides web-hooks for ether and other token based erc20 funds.